# How to break a while loop by not entering a value?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, break

I'm trying to write a very simple program that uses a `while` loop to read in a series of `float` values and calculate their mean, terminating the loop when the user simply presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> without supplying a value.

This is what I have so far, but obviously it produces an error:

```
total = 0
num_values = 0
a = 0

while a != None:
    a = raw_input("Number: ")
    total = total + float(a)
    num_values = num_values + 1

print "The number of values entered was ",num_values
print "The mean is ",total/num_values
```

Error:

```
    total = total + float(a)
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I understand why I get this error but I'm not sure what to do about it. Also, I know this could be done with lists or `try` and `except`, but I need to do it using a `while` loop.

Comment: Why don't you test `a` *before* trying to convert it to a `float`? Also, using a `while` loop doesn't necessarily preclude using `try: except:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test for an *empty string*, and do so *before* converting to a float:

```
while True:
    a = raw_input("Number: ")
    if not a:
        break
    total = total + float(a)
    num_values = num_values + 1
```

This loop is simply endless, and a `break` is executed to exit the loop.